# Display few custom ad banners in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I have an an area at bottom of my app which shows custom banner images from an xml feed which looks like this:

```
<sponsor><image>image1.jpg</image></sponsor>
<sponsor><image>image2.jpg</image></sponsor>
<sponsor><image></image></sponsor>//image node is empty
<sponsor><image></image></sponsor>//image node is empty
<sponsor><image>image3.jpg</image></sponsor>
<sponsor><image>image4.jpg</image></sponsor>
```

I have these images parsed in an array and change the banner ad with time and should repeat the same cycle.

Now I have these images displayed at the display area and the the area goes blank when there is no content in the `<image>` node. What I need is to skip the empty `<image>` nodes and display the content of the node with images.

I'm using this following code:

I have a banner object:

bannerObj.m

```
@implementation bannerObj

@synthesize url,index;

@end
```

this method in my HomepageViewController.m stores the array like below:

```
- (void)processCompleted{

NSMutableArray *bannerArray=[[self sponsorrssParser]sponsorrssItems];
banArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
bannerObj *bannObj = [[bannerObj alloc]init];


NSString *bannerImagestr;
for(int i=0; i<[bannerArray count]; i++){
    bannerImagestr = [[bannerArray objectAtIndex:i] BannerImage];

    NSLog(@"banner image str-------->>> %@",bannerImagestr);

    if(bannerImagestr != nil){

    bannerImagestr  = [ bannerImagestr  stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:bannerImagestr];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
        bannObj.url = img;
        bannObj.index = i;

    [banArray addObject:bannObj];

        NSLog(@"banner array---->>>%@",banArray);

    }
}

[spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

and this is a target method which sets the image on the area.

```
-(void) targetMethod:(id) sender {


int countOfBanners=[banArray count];

NSLog(@"count of banners ----->> %d",countOfBanners);
if(numTimerTicks< countOfBanners)
{

     roundedButtonType.tag = [[banArray objectAtIndex:numTimerTicks]index];
    [roundedButtonType setBackgroundImage:[[banArray objectAtIndex:numTimerTicks]url]forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image
    numTimerTicks++;

}
else{
    numTimerTicks=0;
}

NSLog(@"count of timer ticks ----->> %d",numTimerTicks);
}
```

This sets the last image in the feed and i'm not able to display the other banner images. Can anybody help me out in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops!! I should have called `bannerObj *bannObj = [[bannerObj alloc]init];` inside the for loop.. :D
my bad.. :P